# CHARINDEX weirdness

Tags: sql, t-sql

How would you think the following results be?

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('space and /* comment */', 'Phrase with space and /* comment */') AS MatchPosition;
DECLARE @SearchWord varchar =  'space and /* comment */'
SELECT CHARINDEX(@SearchWord, 'Phrase with space and /* comment */') AS MatchPosition;
SELECT CHARINDEX(@SearchWord, 'Phrase with space and comment') AS MatchPosition;
```

I was anticipating that result 1 and 2 are the same, and result 3 would be zero, but in fact result 2 and 3 are the same, and they are not zero, and not equal to result 1 either.

What's going on?

I didn't seen an of such precaution in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Catch is here:

```
DECLARE @SearchWord varchar =  'space and /* comment */'
SELECT @SearchWord;
-- s
```

> From [char and varchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> "When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, **the default length is 1.**"

Should be:

```
-- defining size to avoid implicit truncating
DECLARE @SearchWord varchar(100) =  'space and /* comment */'
SELECT @SearchWord;
```

---

> *I was anticipating that result 1 and 2 are the same, and result 3 would be zero*

Correct.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('space and /* comment */', 'Phrase with space and /* comment */') AS MatchPosition;
DECLARE @SearchWord varchar(100) =  'space and /* comment */'
SELECT CHARINDEX(@SearchWord, 'Phrase with space and /* comment */') AS MatchPosition;
SELECT CHARINDEX(@SearchWord, 'Phrase with space and comment') AS MatchPosition;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/EOSKZ73026)**